# Sum a list of dict values based on a string

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as below:

```
m = {
        'A':[71.03711,71.0788],
        'R':[156.10111,156.1875],
        'N':[114.04293,114.1038],
        'D':[115.02694,115.0886],
        'C':[103.00919,103.1388],
        'E':[129.04259,129.1155],
        'Q':[128.05858,128.1307],
        'G':[57.02146,57.0519],
        'H':[137.05891,137.1411],
        'I':[113.08406,113.1594],
        'L':[113.08406,113.1594],
        'K':[128.09496,128.1741],
        'M':[131.04049,131.1926],
        'F':[147.06841,147.1766],
        'P':[97.05276,97.1167],
        'S':[87.03203,87.0782],
        'T':[101.04768,101.1051],
        'W':[186.07931,186.2132],
        'Y':[163.06333,163.1760]
    }
```

And I have this string s. I want to calculate the sum as below:

```
s = "ARWYLKNI"

total1 = 0
total2 = 0

for a in s:
    total1 = total1 + m[a][0]
    total2 = total2 + m[a][1]
```

However this is difficult to scale up. I am looking for a more general way to do.

Comment: Scale up / generalize in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print ([sum(l) for l in zip(*[m[a] for a in s])])
```

Output:

```
[1044.58687, 1045.2522]
```

To scale up:

```
sl = ["ARWYLKNI","AFVYLKNI","ARWDLKNI"]

print ([[sum(l) for l in zip(*[m[a] for a in s])] for s in sl])
```

Output:

```
[[1044.58687, 1045.2522], [1044.58687, 1045.2522], [1044.58687, 1045.2522]]
```

If you prefer a dict to be returned:

```
print (dict(zip(sl,[[sum(l) for l in zip(*[m[a] for a in s])] for s in sl])))
```

Output:

```
{'ARWYLKNI': [1044.58687, 1045.2522], 'AFYLKNI': [849.47486, 850.0281], 'ARWDLKNI': [996.55048, 997.1648000000001]}
```

Comment: Thanks Synthase that s the second time you helped me